# HTML not updating in angular tests when injected service changes

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test a component which shows or hides a button based on the current users details. I get the user details from a method on the service. The component uses a getter to make the call to the service method.

**In the component:**

```
get me() {
  return this.sessionService.getMe()
}
```

**In the component's html:**

```
<a id="profile-button" *ngIf="me.loggedIn" routerLink="profile">Profile</a>
```

I need to test that the button is displayed when I am logged in and that it is not displayed when I am not logged in. I'm stubbing the session service as follows:

**In the component spec file:**

```
let sessionServiceStub = {
  currentUser: {
    loggedIn: false
  }

  getMe: function () {
    return this.currentUser
  }
}

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: ['RouterTestingModule'],
    declarations: ['MyComponent'],
    providers: [{provide: SessionService, useValue: sessionServiceStub}],
  }).compileComponents()
}))

beforeEach(() => {
  sessionServiceStub.currentUser = {
    loggedIn = false
  }

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
})
```

At the start of each test I set the loggedOn property on the service stub to true or false, then call `detectChanges()` but the HTML doesn't update as expected. Is this to do with the getter, and if so, how can I force the view to get the new value from the sessionService?

**In the component spec file:**

```
it('shows the button when a user is logged in', () => {
  sessionServiceStub.currentUser.loggedIn = true
  fixture.detectChanges()

  de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#profile-button'))
  el: HTMLAnchorElement = de.nativeElement // TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Why create component in each it? Just create component in root before each once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the sessionServiceStub to the providers array, a new instance is created for the tests. After creating the instance, I was then modifying the original stub and these changes were not available until the next tests (when a new instance was created).

By removing the currentUser from the stub, any changes made to it will still be available to the tests as the new instance will reference the same currentUser object.

```
let currentUser: {
  loggedIn: false
}

let sessionServiceStub = {


  getMe: function () {
    return currentUser
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the fixture.detectChanges() from the beforeEach method.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  sessionServiceStub.currentUser = {
    loggedIn = false
  }

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

})
```

It should work fine.

Comment: It's because your `sessionServiceStub.currentUser.loggedIn` property is set to `false` in the `beforeEach` function. Once you get into the `it` function, it's already too late. In order for this method to work, you have to deffer the setting of this property until you get into each `it` function.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take the following approach: `describe` functions can be nested within other `describe` functions. This gives you the possibility to structure your tests into several sections, that will share common boiler plate, as follows.

**Warning: the following code is strictly informative and has not been tested.**

```
describe('MyComponentUnderTestComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponentUnderTestComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponentUnderTestComponent>

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: ['RouterTestingModule'],
      declarations: ['MyComponent'],
      providers: [{provide: SessionService, useValue: sessionServiceStub}],
    }).compileComponents()
  }))

  describe('when user is connected', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      sessionServiceStub.currentUser.loggedIn = true
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)
      component = fixture.componentInstance
      fixture.detectChanges()
    })

    it('shows the button when a user is logged in', () => {
      de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#profile-button'))
      el: HTMLAnchorElement = de.nativeElement
      // ...
    })
  })

  describe('when user is NOT connected', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      sessionServiceStub.currentUser.loggedIn = false
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)
      component = fixture.componentInstance
      fixture.detectChanges()
    })
  })

  it('does NOT show the button when a user is NOT logged in', () => {
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#profile-button'))
    el: HTMLAnchorElement = de.nativeElement
    // ...
  })
})
```

This approach is a bit more complex at first site, then the one you have taken. However, it has several benefits:

1. The nested `describe` functions create different contexts within your tests: "*user is logged in*" vs "*user is not logged in*". It helps mutualizing boiler plates for tests that share the same context.
2. Therefore, it separates completely different test cases within your file.
3. It uses `beforeEach` functions to set-up context ("*user is logged in*", "*user is not logged in*") where it is supposed to be, instead of doing it "on the fly", in `it` functions, where it might be difficult to spot for other devs (even for yourself in a few days from now).

Comment: The approach is nice and I'm going to use the nested describes in future, but it's still not updating the currentUser object. In the "when user is NOT connected" `describe` block I'm seeing behaviour I would expect with loggedIn=true. It works f I slot another `it` block at the start of that `describe` block before the button test, but the value for the new test is wrong.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that the `loggedIn` property is set at the very begining of the file. I think it is clouding all other values. Try to only declare the `sessionServiceStub` at the begining and defer the setting of the `loggedIn` property until reaching the inner `beforeEach`.